# Trouble Using setInterval function

Tags: javascript, setinterval

I'm having some trouble getting the below to work. I'm trying to run this asynchronous function called Chat.fetch and I can get the messages it returns to display correctly. When I try to pass it through setInterval it will return the chat messages once but not refresh them every 3 seconds which is what I'm trying to do. Any direction would be awesome. Thanks!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
   <script src="http://chatbuilder.hackreactor.com/ChatBuilder.js"></script>
  </head>
    <body>
      <script>
         Chat.guide.start();
      </script>


  <h2>Borken Chat</h2>

  <input class="draft" type="text"/> <button class="send" disabled>send</button>



  <ul class="messages">


     PrintChat=function(Chat_Messages){
       var y=Chat_Messages.length;
       for(i=0;i<y;i++){
         Chat.display(Chat_Messages[i]);
       }
     }

   PrintMessages=Chat.fetch(PrintChat);
   setInterval(PrintMessages,3000);


  </script>

</ul>
```

Comment: If it's asynchronous, you are supposed to wait for it (instead of randomly firing your display function every 3 seconds)? Check out their docs.

Comment: Any direction? I'm missing an opening `<script>` tag, some closing ones for your html and body as well as a doctype declaration and  `<title>` element.

Comment: it's there in the code, just forgot while copy pasting. Sorry.

Comment: the instructions are to use setTimeout or setInterval to get it to refresh the messages from the server every 3 seconds.

Comment: Which script are you using, anyway? Please link to its docs/homepage.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function fetchNew() {
 var PrintChat=function(Chat_Messages){
   var y=Chat_Messages.length;
   for(i=0;i<y;i++){
     Chat.display(Chat_Messages[i]);
   }
 }
 Chat.fetch(PrintChat);
}

setInterval(fetchNew,3000);
```

The problem in your original code is that `PrintMessages` is the *result* of calling a function, rather than function itself.

Comment: Hey thanks man it works! So the trick was just to embed the result as a variable in a funtion and then run setInterval that way?

Comment: The key idea is that the first argument to setInterval needs to be an actual function.  In your original code were giving it the result of *evaluating* a function.  So I just made a new function which did what you wanted, ie, a function which "calls Chat.fetch, passing Chat.fetch the PrintChat function as an argument."  So Chat.fetch itself also takes a function as an argument, just like setInterval does, though of course they are different functions.